# 'bluemix-plugin-repo' does not exist as an available plug-in repo. Check the name and try again

Tags: ibm-cloud, autoscaling

I'm trying to setup the Autoscaling Plugin as described in the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/auto-scaling/index.html):

```
snowch$ bluemix plugin repo-add bluemix-plugin-repo https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net
FAILED
Plug-in repo URL https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net already exists. Try a different URL.
```

So I tried:

```
snowch$ bluemix plugin install auto-scaling -r bluemix-plugin-repo
Looking up 'auto-scaling' from repository 'bluemix-plugin-repo'...
FAILED
'bluemix-plugin-repo' does not exist as an available plug-in repo. Check the name and try again.
```

Note my version:

```
snowch$ bluemix --version
bluemix version 0.5.4+ae22935-2017-05-18T06:24:28+00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the command from:

```
snowch$ bluemix plugin install auto-scaling -r bluemix-plugin-repo
```

to:

```
snowch$ bluemix plugin install auto-scaling -r Bluemix
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I have asked the service team to review the referenced documentation.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've also submitted a PR: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix-Docs/cli/pull/2

Answer (score 0):

plugin repo  https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net with name 'Bluemix' is added by default, so you don't need to add that repo before you install plugins from it.